# can't get the viewwidth after the first layout and the intent doesn't works

Tags: android, admob

I have this problem 
"can't get the viewwidth after the first layout"
running my app on phone and emulator with 3.2 or less android.
the error is from the ad, but it works.
what is not work is the intent on imageView.

Here is the code.

```
ImageView Image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image);
Image.setClickable(true);
Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View V) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(V.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

In the manifest

```
android:minSdkVersion="5"
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?  Starting the activity?

Comment: Clicking on the image nothing happen

Comment: Checkout the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `onClick` code woth that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The first parameter in the `intent` constructor should be the current `context` of your app now. If `getActivity()` did not work try `getApplicationContext()`

Note: make sure that this method is being called when you click on the item by debugging.  This answer will help you know how to debug https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111164/1364896

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by putting the code in "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { "
instead of "public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {"